# Reference for $X' = \{ \lambda ||\cdot||'(x) : \lambda \in \mathbb R,\quad x \in X \setminus \{ 0 \} \}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

I would like to find a reference for the equality
$$
X' =  \{  \lambda ||\cdot||'(x) : \lambda \in \mathbb R,\quad x \in X \setminus \{ 0 \} \}
$$
when $X$ is a real uniformly convex Banach space whose norm is differentiable outside of $0$. I came to this result reading Villani's lecture notes on integration.

Comment: I don't have a reference, but for $x^* \in X^*$, you could try to minimize $\langle x^*, x\rangle$ over $x \in X$ with $\|x\|=1$. Then, the KKT conditions yield $x^* = \lambda \|\cdot\|'(x)$.

Comment: It works and it is astonishing. Thank you very much!! For people reading this: it works also for reflexive spaces.

Comment: Was it these set of notes? https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2013/03/IAF.pdf

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes it was these ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the idea of @gerw here is my solution. Taking the usefull informations of @Jochen I give two distinct solutions.

Suppose $X$ is reflexive and not $\{ 0 \}$, so that its unit sphere $\mathbb S_X$ is non void and its unit closed ball $\overline{\mathbb B}_X$ is weakly quasi compact by Kakutani. Also suppose that the norm on $X$ is Gâteaux differentiable on $X \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

**Sequential solution** :
By Krein Smulian $\overline{\mathbb B}_X$ is in fact sequentially compact. Let $x^* \in X' \setminus \{ 0 \}$, let $(x_j)$ be a minimizing sequence of $x^*$ on $\mathbb S_X \subset \overline{\mathbb B}_X$. By sequential compactness let $\sigma$ extraction and $x_\infty \in \overline{\mathbb B}_X$ such that $(x_{\sigma(j)})$ goes weakly to $x_\infty$. Observe that since $x^* \neq 0$ and since $x^*$ is weakly continuous
$$
0 > \inf_{\mathbb S_X} x^* = \lim_j \langle x^* , x_{\sigma(j)} \rangle  = \langle x^* , x_\infty \rangle
$$
so that $x_\infty$ is non zero. Then the optimality property of $x_\infty$ gives
$$
\frac{1}{||x_\infty||} \langle x^* , x_\infty \rangle = \left\langle x^* , \frac{x_\infty}{||x_\infty||} \right\rangle \geq \langle x^* , x_\infty \rangle
$$
so that $x_\infty \in \mathbb S_X$. Observe that then $x_\infty$ is a minimizer of $\varphi(x) = \frac{\langle x^*,x \rangle}{||x||}$ on $\mathbb B(x_\infty, 1)$ so that
$$
0 = \varphi'(x_\infty) = x^* - \langle x^* x_\infty \rangle ||\cdot ||'(x_\infty).
$$

**Topological solution** : The map $x^*$ defined on $\overline{\mathbb B}_X$ endowed of the weak topology of $X$ is continuous on a non empty quasi compact space so it has a minimizer $x_\infty$. The rest of the proof is as above.

Comment: The **sphere** $\{x\in X: \|x\|=1\}$ is not weakly compact but you only use weak compactness of the **ball**. Moreover, you use weak **sequential** compactness which is okay by the Krein-Smulian theorem.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the typo. However I do not understand why Krein-Smulian would help. Also I do not understand your point on sequential compactness, the weak topology of a normed space is Hausdorff so topological compacts are sequentially compact.

Comment: **NO!** Compactness does not imply sequential compactness. For example, the unit ball of $X=\ell_\infty$ is weak$^*$-compact by Alaoglu's theorem but the sequence of evaluations $e_n\in \ell_\infty^*$ (defined by $e_n(x)=x_n$) does not have a weak$^*$-convergent subsequence.

Comment: sorry, I meant the dual unit ball of $\ell_\infty^*$.

Comment: Wow you just taught me that compact is not necessarily sequentially compact, I am endebted for that, thank you.